# Dynamic network interface for Compute Instance module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, gcloud

We've Terraform module that creates compute_instance.
Some instances should get public IP.
Public IP created when you define "access_config {}" property under network_interface:

```
network_interface {
  network = "default"
  access_config {

  }
}
```

We try to inject dynamically the network interface and the access_config from 
"production/Main.tf" that called to this module:

```
module "arbiter" {
  source                = "../modules/compute"
  name                  = "arbiter"
  machine_type          = "custom-1-2048"
  zones                 = ["europe-west2-a"]
  tags                  = ["mongo-db"]
  metadata              = {
    sshKeys             = "${var.ssh_user}:${file("ssh-keys/main.rsa.pub")}"
  }
  network_interface = { -> this line is worng
    network = "default"
  }
}
```

How can we inject a dynamic object to network_interface property?
Is it possible with Terraform if not, What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `arbiter` module do this:

```
variable "external_ip" {
  description = "Controls if VM gets external IP"
  default     = false
}

locals {
  access_config = {
    "0" = []
    "1" = [{}]
  }
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "arbiter" {
  name         = "${var.name}"
  machine_type = "${var.type}"
  zone         = "${var.zones}"
  tags         = "${var.tags}"
  metadata     = "${var.metadata}"

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "some/image"
    }
  }

  network_interface {
    network = "default"

    access_config = "${local.access_config[var.external_ip]}"
  }
}
```

Then, when using the module, you can specify `external_ip` variable to indicate that VM should be accessible from the internet.

```
module "arbiter" {
  source       = "../modules/compute"
  name         = "arbiter"

  machine_type = "custom-1-2048"
  zones        = ["europe-west2-a"]
  tags         = ["mongo-db"]

  metadata = {
    sshKeys = "${var.ssh_user}:${file("ssh-keys/main.rsa.pub")}"
  }

  external_ip = true
}
```

---

More details about Terraform and `null` values tricks: [Null values in Terraform v0.11.x](https://beatcracker.wordpress.com/2019/03/09/null-values-in-terraform-v0-11-x/)